# How to merge .csv files given some conditions?

Tags: python, python-2.7, file, python-3.x, csv

I have several `.csv` files in one directory. 
I would like to iterate over those files an merge/combine them into a single .csv file  given some condition.

Each file uses the same naming convention:

```
Date       Name   City   Supervisor

2015-01-01_Steve__Boston_Steven.csv
2015-10-03_Michael_Dallas_Thomas.csv
2015-02-10_John_NewYork_Michael.csv
```

Each file contains only one column with varying length:

```
2015-01-01_Steve__Boston_Steven.csv

Sales
100
20
3
100
200
```

or

```
2015-10-03_Michael_Dallas_Thomas.csv

Sales
1
2

2015-02-10_John_NewYork_Michael.csv
```

or

```
Sales
1
2
3
```

Because the header "Sales" in each file might be named differently I would like to skip the first row and beginn always with the second row.

I would like to get a final table containing the following information:

```
Sales Name     City    Supervisor
100   Steve    Boston  Steven
20    Steve    Boston  Steven
30    Steve    Boston  Steven
3     Steve    Boston  Steven
100   Steve    Boston  Steven
200   Steve    Boston  Steven
1     Michael  Dallas  Thomas
2     Michael  Dallas  Thomas
1     John     NewYork Michael
2     John     NewYork Michael
3     John     NewYork Michael
```

Im new to python so apologize for the inconvenience.

What I have tried:

```
import pandas as pd
from os import listdir

source_path, dst_path = '/oldpath', '/newpath'

files = [f for f in listdir(source_path) if f.endswith('.csv')]

def combining_data(files):
    df_list = []
    for filename in files:
        df_list.append(pd.read_csv(filename))

combining_data(files)
```

But that unfortunately is doesnt produces the required output

Comment: Check my solution with pandas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
import os

df=pd.DataFrame(columns=['Sales','Name','City','Supervisor'])
files = [f for f in os.listdir('.') if f.startswith('2015')]

for a in files:
    df1 = pd.read_csv(a, header=None, skiprows=1, names=['Sales'])
    len1 = len(df1.index)
    f = [b for b in a.split('_') if b]
    l2, l3 = [f[1], f[2], f[3][:-4]], ['Name','City','Supervisor']
    for b,c in zip(l2,l3):
        ser = pd.Series(data=[b for _ in range(len1)],index=range(len1))
        df1[c]=ser
    df = pd.concat([df,df1],axis=0)
df.index = range(len(df.index))
df.to_csv('new_csv.csv', index=None)
df
```

Output:

[image]

```
CPU times: user 16 ms, sys: 0 ns, total: 16 ms
Wall time: 22.6 ms
```

Comment: Thx for providing your answer. Using python 3.5  I get the error however: 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
`TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-31-a7997d497c4d> in <module>()
      2     df1=pd.read_csv(a)
      3     f = filter(None,a.split('_'))
----> 4     n,c,s = f[1], f[2], f[3][:-4]
      5     len1 = len(df01.index)

TypeError: 'filter' object is not subscriptable `

Comment: @Mamba removed the filter() part which was causing error because of python3. Try again.

Comment: Ok, it return now `ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer`

Comment: @Mamba Ok modified the code. Try again. Let it be float for now. Let's just first make it work so that we can throw a party :P :)

Comment: cool, now it returns dataframe, have zo check whether its correct yet :-) but thank you a lot!!

Comment: @Mamba You were just butchering my code. Good now it's working :)

Comment: One last question, where in the code do you skip the first row? Because "Sales" might be named differently, it makes sense to skip the first row

Answer (score 2):

This requires multiple steps. First, I would parse the CSV names to grab the Name, City, and Supervisor. From the looks of it, you can use a `split` on the name to grab those values. Then, you have to read the files and append them to a new CSV. Also using pandas is a little bit of overkill. You can use the csv module.

```
import csv
import os

files = [f for f in os.listdir(source_path) if f.endswith('.csv')]

with open(os.path.join(source_path, 'new_csv.csv'), 'wb') as new:
    writer = csv.writer(new)
    writer.writerow(['Sales','Name','City','Supervisor'])  # write the header for the new csv
    for f in files:
        split = f[:-4].split('_')  # split the filename on _, while removing the .csv
        name = split[1]  # extract the name
        city = split[2]  # extract the city
        supervisor = split[3]  # extract the supervisor
        with open(os.path.join(source_path, f), 'rb') as readfile:
            reader = csv.reader(readfile)
            reader.next()  # Skip the header from the file you're reading
            for row in reader:
                writer.writerow([row[0], name, city, supervisor])  # write to the new csv
```

Comment: Thx for your suggestion. I get the error however: 
` TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-51-a3f76dbfc62f> in <module>()
      1 with open(os.path.join(source_path, 'new_csv.csv'), 'wb') as new:
      2     writer = csv.writer(new)
----> 3     writer.writerow(['Sales','Name','City','Supervisor'])  # write the header for the new csv
      4     for f in files:
      5         split = f[:-4].split('_')  # split the filename on _, while removing the .csv

TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str' `

Comment: Where do you take the second row instead the header?

Comment: @Mamba Hmm, it looks like you're using Python 3.5. In this case, you want to use `[b'Sales',b'Name',b'City',b'Supervisor']`. You could also attempt to open without binary mode: `open(os.path.join(source_path, 'new_csv.csv'), 'w')`. That will write in text mode instead of binary mode. The second row is taken when I used the `reader.next()` command. That skips a row when reading the file.

Comment: Also, if you plan to write in text mode, then read the files in text mode too: `with open(os.path.join(source_path, f), 'r') as readfile:`.

Comment: @Scratch'N'Purr Your's is 16 lines. With pandas its 17 lines :) You can still make it more compact though.

Comment: `CPU times: user 16 ms, sys: 0 ns, total: 16 ms
Wall time: 22.6 ms`